# Google Cloud OAuth consent screen not reflecting changes to scope of (internal) app

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

### Background

I initially set my Google Cloud application up with the full Google Drive scope (`../auth/drive`) and tested the connection to my personal account (i.e. gave the app permission). I am using `PyDrive` FYI.

I subsequently deleted the app from my personal account (*Disconnect from Drive*), removed the full scope in the *OAuth consent screen* settings and replaced it with just the `../auth/drive.file` scope.

I then deleted the OAuth credentials and recreated them (and re-downloaded them to my machine), just to be on the safe side.

### Expected behaviour

When presented with the OAuth screen, I now expect the scope to reflect that the app only will have access to the files and folders it has created itself.

### Actual behaviour

The OAuth consent screen still tells me the app will have access to **all** files and folders in my Drive.

### Code I am using to authenticate

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

...

    gauth = GoogleAuth()

    gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("app_user_secrets.json")

    if gauth.credentials is None:
        gauth.GetFlow()
        gauth.flow.params.update({"access_type": "offline"})
        gauth.flow.params.update({"approval_prompt": "force"})
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    elif gauth.access_token_expired:
        gauth.Refresh()
    else:
        gauth.Authorize()

    gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("app_user_secrets.json")

    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

---

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can work around it?

Comment: I've seen https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704 but I don't believe it is relevant.

Comment: Are you using a Service account? What scopes do you have in your application? Can you provide your (sanitised) authentication flow?

Comment: I have two service accounts set up, both default - one for App Engine and one for Compute Engine. The only scopes I (now) have on my consent screen are `email`, `profile`, `openid` and `../auth/drive.file`. I am not sure what you mean with "authentication flow", but will update the question with the code I run to authenticate.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `PyDrive` sets its own OAuth scopes by default unless you overwrite them. The default is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` as outlined here: https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#automatic-and-custom-authentication-with-settings-yaml.

I fixed and overrode this by editing my authentication flow and including the following line before the `LocalWebserverAuth()` command.

```py
gauth.settings["oauth_scope"] = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]
```

Another alternative would have been to author my own `settings.yaml` file but I did not want to go down that route.